# Any good GUI tool to easily create stored procs SQL server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

The templates for stored-procs in SSMS do not auto-populate all input columns, again there is manual work involved.

I am looking for something like right-click on table and say CREATE stored-proc, and then it allows to pick a template, based on which it can populate the parameters etc. and give check-box in GUI (like table designer, you can easily add/remove a column).

Some support for change management with table undergoing alter or otherwise would also be helpful.

Currently we manually write all stored-procs, which i think we should be able to save time and labor with automation.

Any suggestion on other free 3rd party tools ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SSMS tools pack](https://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) has user configurable templates to generate [CRUD stored procedures](https://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=11#CRUD).

Example template

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [ssmstoolspack.com](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Images/Features/CRUDOptions3.png))</sub>